# Not a constructor error within jQuery.on

Tags: jquery, constructor

Given the following code:

```
var test;
this.test = function() {
//...
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$(this).on('click', function(e) {
test = new test();
//...
```

I always get test is not a constructor. Why?

Comment: should be `var test = function(){ }`  This will get you started with basics OOPS in JS .. http://www.slideshare.net/After2050/oops-in-javascript-4877770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EDIT: Constructor and also adding a variable to the Test type:

```
function Test(){
    this.something = 'hello';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
     var test = new Test();
     alert(test.something);
    });
```

});

This will result in alert with 'hello' text.
Adapting your code, you can also do:

```
var test = {
    something: "hello"
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
     var test = new Object();
     alert(test.something);
    });
});
```

Comment: My Javascript is... lacking. Could you explain why your code works and the other does not?

Comment: "test" is a var, not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

var test  != this.test;

new test() points to the variable test which is not the one you declare as a function.